# How anonymous users are able to complete survey, even when webform is set only for registered users

Tags: webforms, users

I have used [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module for gathering user data before accessing the content.
Only authenticated users can access the webform, but in the webform submission reports there are some user names with name as anonymous who submitted the webform.

Answer (score 0):

Admin menu --> webform --> Choose one of your webform and click component--> form setting

Under SUBMISSION ACCESS untick anonymous user.

Comment: it is already set to be access only by authenticated users.
in most of the cases username comes properly but in some of the cases the username comes as anonymous( not verified )

Comment: how about take a look at your database? database table is user. Compare different between database and webform's result. Maybe because of special character.

Comment: i checked the drupal logs. in the logs its taking email address properly. but while sending admin emails and webform reports it shows anonymous user

Answer (score 0):

[image: Kindly refer to this image]it is already set to be access only by authenticated users.
in most of the cases username comes properly but in some of the cases the username comes as anonymous( not verified )

Comment: What happens if a user's session expires while filling out the form?

Comment: im not able to reproduce this on various networks

Comment: Hi @michael can you help me to forcefully expire a drupal website session?

Comment: Delete your browser cookie?

Comment: i tried to reproduce the same using various test cases but it didnt reproduce on my end.